# How to use external data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm building the model using the internal data to predict the health situation of the customer. I've just found about 100 new "external data" in the form of region data. Based on this new information, I create a first new variable "Diabetes" i.e over 100 people in Lazio, 14.1 of them have the diabetes; this number in Milan is 15, ...

There are still 100 variables like this, for example here: "Hypertension", which is also linked to "Region", like "Diabetes", i.e if two prospects have the different value for "Diabetes", they will have also different value for "Hypertension", and vice versa. My questions are:

1. Should I add "Hypertension" into the model?
2. Does "Hypertension" add the new information into our model with respect to the variable Diabetes?
3. How can I use all of the 100 new variables in the most effective way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can bring in the external data, and you may want to consider a multilevel or hierarchical model when you do so, given then many of your variables will be grouped by region. A good explanation of multilevel models can be found [here](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/multilevel-models/what-why.html).

The typical example is estimating test performance in schools - you have individual characteristics of each of the students, but then you also have school-specific characteristics - this would seem to be a good analogy for the problem you've described.